# Remove a file from a WEB App on Linux in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, remove

I have a WP website hosted in Azure as Web App on Linux so I'm root. I tried to make an update to a plugin and received a crash. I stopped to app and tried to remove the plugin's leftovers. It says Access denied, or file does not exists, etc. I restarted the app, logged in as root and tried to remove it with rm. It can't be removed either. I tried to chmod the file. The command doesn't return any error but I still can't remove the file.

It always says I do not have read permissions. If I want to mv the file it doesn't let me either. If I want to overwrite it, the same.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Ciprian

Comment: If you want help show the current state, not only a vague description. Show the permissions of the files and directories,  the commands you executed and their complete output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've lost my patience with Azure and have restored the entire web app from a previous state. After that, I did remove the files. So, I used a workaround solution, it is not the best option. Thanks for your trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

Connect with ftp or sftp to the web app, and check where the plugin stores it files and delete those.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure#appservice

If that doesn't work try to restart the app service using PowerShell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/restart-azwebapp?view=azps-11.3.0